# Simple CGI/Perl Script not displaying background image

Tags: perl, cgi

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use CGI qw(:standard);
print header;
print start_html(-title=>"Hello World", 
-bgcolor=>"#cccccc", -text=>"#999999",
-background=>"healo.jpg");
```

The color displays, but not the image.
I have the healo.jpg located in the bin folder and my home folder.
I took this code from http://www.cgi101.com/book/ch1/text.html
Please help.

Comment: Is the image in the same directory as your perl script?

Comment: Yes it is in the same directory. I just tried to go to it directly though and it gives me a 404 not found error. I don't understand. K this is the test page: http://csvlife.com/cgi-bin/frt.cgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CGI script is in a standard `cgi-bin`, the file `healo.jpg` cannot be stored there because it is not a CGI script. Try putting it somewhere else.

For example, you could put the image file in your wwwroot, so that you can find it at http://csvlife.com/healo.jpg (there's already something there), and then change that part of the code to `-background=>"/healo.jpg"`.

Comment: Okay. If I do that do I list the image path in this: -background=>"healo.jpg"                                            part of the code?

Comment: Yes. For example, you could put the image file in your wwwroot, so that you can find it at http://csvlife.com/healo.jpg (there's already something there), and then change that part of the code to `-background=>"/healo.jpg"`.

Comment: @nandhp you might want to edit your answer to include your comment, so that others who search and find this post see the actual answer (relative v. absolute path issue) - especially since this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Examine your generated HTML.  That's going to generate a background attribute of the form:

```
background = 'healo.jpg'
```

This means healo.jpg needs to be in the same directory as wherever you currently are, which is likely not the same as your home folder.

You'll either need to copy the image to the webroot (which you likely can't do), or change the argument to `start_html` to be an absolute path, e.g. `background ='/healo.jpg'`

Comment: /public_html/healo.jpg is the path that I have it in now and it shows up when I goto http://csvlife.com/healo.jpg but the other page still doesn't display it...Also thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: What's the generated source for the script show?  In other words, when you load the cgi in a browser, view src.  What's the body tag look like?

Comment: Perl does't care about existence of file healo.jpg, it only outputs `background` attribute.  As file healo.jpg is places "/healo.jpg", it should be `-background=>"/healo.jpg"` or `-background=>"../healo.jpg"`

Comment: @DieVers updated my answer to clarify.  Basically this is an absolute v. relative path issue.  You'll want to use an absolute path.

Comment: @DieVers as an aside, the CGI library is a bit dated.  For example, the `background` attribute to a `<body>` tag is deprecated for HTML 4.  You might want to look at some newer/more current technologies instead.